# NSPredicate: compare only part of string?

Tags: arrays, nspredicate

I have an array of person_name###country_name:

```
Bob###USA
Tim###UK
Sandy###German
```

I have a UISearchBar which looks for person name(ie. does not consider country), the following NSPredicate searches person name as well as country, how do I re-construct it so it only looks for person name?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", __searchTerm];
NSArray *result = [self.source filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

the array of person###country is created by some complex way, so do not suggest me create another array with only person names, also, different countries can have different people of the same name.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You would use `BEGINSWITH` instead of `CONTAINS`.

But really: if the two pieces of data are separate, why are you storing then in the same string?  You should break them apart and create a new class with two properties: `name` and `country`. That will make all of this *much* simpler.

Comment: Thanks, but BEGINSWITH does not work if I search for "ob" where "Bob###USA" should be returned and BEGINSWITH does not return it.